# What is !! operator means in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is a double **!!** operator means in JavaScript? I tried to look into JS docs operator and I can't find out what is **!!** means for.

```
!!item.length && (!!item.sum || !!item.indicator)
```

Comment: it's literally two ! operators, firstly it negates the value, and then negates it again, giving you a boolean representation of the value, people just tend to prefer writing `!!val` over `Boolean(val)`. It saves characters making it easier for browsers to download script files, for instance google compilers even turn `false` into `!1` to save characters so there are reasons behind writing it this way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript#:~:text=55,10%20false%20%3D%3D%3D%20!!0

Comment: it basically converts variables into boolean

Comment: Ohh okay thank you guys, much appreciate!